# NVD3 - x axis labels fail

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to customize the x-axis label for a line plot with NV D3 but all I get is the iteration from 0 - N

Here's my code

```
    for(var i = 0;i< numberBins;i++){
        valuesForD3.push({x:parseFloat(histogramObject['min']) + parseFloat(i * histogramObject['binWidth']),
                          y:histogramObject['values'][i]
                         });
    }

chart = nv.models.lineChart()
          .options({
            margin: {left: 50, bottom: 40},
            x: function(d,i) { return i},
            showXAxis: true,
            showYAxis: true,
            transitionDuration: 100
          });


d3.select('#chart1 svg')
            .datum([{values:valuesForD3,key:'Score values',color:'#2222ff'}])
            .call(chart);
```

Comment: Share some of your data with us.

Comment: You can find the view here : http://localize.pytom.org/php/result.php?jobID=tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their examples (where's the documentation!), you can customize the ticks like:

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d.someTickLabel;
  });
```

Here's a quick [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TT9KgxOv3QsXF8lkDoRG?p=preview).